# I am wondering how I would be able to have my GitHub contributions show to my GitHub account from when I push from my terminal on my mac.

Tags: github

I am wondering how I would be able to have my GitHub contributions show to my GitHub account from when I push from my terminal on my mac. I am a brand new developer sorry for the newbie question!

Comment: Can you please clarify? Your contribution status is automatically updated in your profile on a daily basis. Unless I misunderstood your question, I don't think you need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do on your Mac is make sure your user.name/user.email are set to your GitHub login/email account.

See "[Setting your username in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/)".

That means your commits will be recorded as "you" (on GitHub) and your contributions will be updated accordingly.

Comment: I hadn't tried this before, I added the same email I use for my Github account in the terminal after reading this, however, it still seems not to have appeared in my contribution log on GitHub.

Comment: @Jonathan Did you push new commits done with this email? Because that will only import your contribution for new commits, not your past contribution.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a private repository you have to enable/activate `private contributions` in `Contribution settings` under your profile.

[image]